# A proper definition for homogeneous coordinates in geometric image formation

Tags: definition, projective-geometry, image-processing, computer-vision

In my computer vision course, we apply homogenous coordinates to represent points in 2D or 3D space. However, in my course it lacks a proper definition of what homogeneous coordinates are.

I have found according to Wikipedia that they are a system of coordinates used in projective geometry, as Cartesian coordinates are used in Euclidean geometry.

Therefore, what would be a proper definition of homogenous coordinates in  geometrical formation of images because I don't understand how much projective geometry differs from cartesian coordinates.

Comment: This series of articles may help: https://medium.com/@daniel.j.lenton/multiple-view-geometry-series-cd4966d75c40 , they are based on the seminal book ["Multiple-View-Geometry-Computer-Vision"](https://www.amazon.es/Multiple-View-Geometry-Computer-Vision/dp/0521623049)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following figure:

It explains that the fondamental property of homogeneous coordinates to be "up to a factor" here
$$(x,y,z) \equiv \left(\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{z}=1\right) $$

is in correspondence with the fundamental process of vision : an observer whose eye is situated at the origin of 3D coordinates sees a 3D object (here a cube) through rays that intersect a kind of "screen" situated at $z=1$ (in fact this screen could placed  at any height $z=z_0>0$) ; the 2D resulting image of the edges is the 2D rendering of the real 3D object...

[image]

This graphical example shows that in fact,

- a point in 2D projective geometry is a line issued from the origin in 3D space with homogeneous coordinates,
- in the same way, a line in 2D proj. geom. is a plane passing through the origin in 3D space, etc.